# how do I inject a service from an angular library to another angular library

Tags: angular

I have to angular libraries in the projects folder

```
ng generate library foo
ng generate library bar
```

My foo library contain a public_api.ts which wrap the library files

```
export * from './lib/foo.service';
```

I have a service in foo define as abstract class

```
export abstract class FooService {}
```

I want to extend the fooService in a Bar service

```
import { FooService } from 'projects/foo/src/public_api';
export class BarService extends FooService{}
```

I got this error

```
BUILD ERROR
error TS6059: File '/projects/foo/src/lib/foo.service.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'projects/bar/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
error TS6059: File '/projects/foo/src/public_api.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '//projects/bar/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

How I can get my foo library from bar?

Answer (score 3):

Try to treat libraries as a separate projects (even if they are located inside a single source tree).

How to make your approach work: (starting from scratch)

1. `ng new libs-test`
2. `ng generate library foo`
3. `ng generate library bar`
4. `ng build foo`
5. `npm i foo@file:dist/foo` *// this adds a local dependency for your app project to the foo library*
6. Open the package.json of the libary `bar` and add the `"foo": "latest"` dependency:

```
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^7.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "^7.2.0",
        "foo": "latest" // add this line
      }
    }
```

7. Go the the `BarService` inside the `bar` library:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { FooService } from 'foo';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class BarService extends FooService{

      constructor() {
        super();
      }
    }
```

**Please note the non-relative `import { FooService } from 'foo';`**

8. Build your `bar` library: `ng build bar`

That's it! Your `bar` library correctly uses the `foo` functionality.

If you want to use the `bar`'s service in your app simply do the following:

9. `ng build bar`
10. `npm i bar@file:dist/bar`
11. In your `AppComponent`:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { BarService } from 'bar';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'libs-test';

      constructor(private barService: BarService) {

      }
    }
```

12. Make sure your app is building properly: `ng build --aot`